# Dependency injection of object initialised by specific value - CDI and Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, cdi, spring-jersey

I have a legacy application which uses Spring for bean management (AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext) and CDI (inject, brought by jersey-spring dependency) for DI.

I have the following situation:

```
@Service
@RequestScoped
@Scope(value = "request")
public class InjectedClass {
     private SomeEnum someAttribute;

     public void getSomeAttribute() {
          return someAttribute;
     }
}

@Service
public class MiddleLayer {
         @Inject
         public MiddleLayer(InjectedClass injectedClass) {
                
         }

         private void middleLayerMethod() {
             if (someAttribute == SomeEnum.Y) {
                  // do something specific
             } 
         }
}


// controller
public class SomeController { 
         @Inject
         // In this flow injectedClass instance is initialised with SomeAttribute = Y by ContainerRequestFilter
        public SomeController(MiddleLayer middleLayer) {
                
        }

        public void someMethod () {
               MethodResult result = middleLayer.middleLayerMethod();
               // do some additional things with result
        }
}

@Component
public class PeriodicActivity {
        @Inject
        // I need this MiddleLayer to be injected with injectedClass instance where SomeAttribute = X, since it doesn't go via request filter
        public PeriodicActivity(MiddleLayer middleLayer) {
                
        }

        public void method () {
               MethodResult result = middleLayer.middleLayerMethod();
               // do some other things with result
        }
}
```

Without DI what I need to happen would look like this:

```
public class PeriodicActivity() {
       InjectedClass injectedClassObjA = new InjectedClass();
       injectedClassObjA.setSomeAttribute(X);
       MiddleLayer middleLayer = new MiddleLayer(injectedClassObjA);
       middleLayer.middleLayerMethod();
}
```

I am looking to do something similar with dependencies.
After some reading I am starting to wonder whether it is possible.

Comment: Do you mean `@Bean` methods?

Comment: @Antoniossss No, regular methods. 
Methods that use MiddleLayer object.
I will change the code to make sure it is clear.

Comment: Are you *actually* using CDI? `@javax.inject.Inject` is part of a more generic specification, implemented by DI libraries like Spring, CDI, Guice.

Comment: I dont know what is the requirement here. I have no idea what *I am looking to do something similar with dependencies.* means in the context of your example.